# Changing the distance metric in ObjectiveHTML's Google Maps

Tags: add-on, google-maps-for-ee, fieldtype

I'm using the Google Map Add-On from ObjectiveHTML. When entering a route using the field type in an EE channel entry the distance (as displayed in "Show Details") is always displayed in Kilometers. Does anyone know how this can be changed to display in miles?

Answer (score 2):

I uploaded a screenshot of my default setup. I simply create a Gmap field and create a route with an origin and destination. You can see my distance is in miles. I think Google is trying to automatically determine which metric to use.

I think what you propose is a good idea though. Being able to force that metric to be something would be nice. I will do some testing to figure out how to best get that data changed and I will report back here. But for now, I don't think it's a problem with the code, rather we just need a way to override the default.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. It would be good to over-ride the metric as it appears that Google thinks we want to see KM despite the fact that we actually use Miles here in the UK.

Comment: I managed to get around this problem by modifying gmap_field.js (in gmap's themes folder). I changed line 1068 to:

`var distance  =  Math.round((leg.distance.value *  0.000621371192)) +  ' miles (' + leg.distance.text + ')';`

Comment: It seems as though the results are returned from Google in either miles or KM depending on how the route request is made (by address or by latitude/longitude) See:
 [link]https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#UnitSystems
However when I test it I always seem to get KM
@tom-davies

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure Justin (ObjectiveHTML) will correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't think there is a way to configure this as an option on the FT at current. It [is possible](https://objectivehtml.com/google-maps/documentation/tag/search#metric) to set a `metric` param on `{exp:gmap:search}` but that's no help here.

THough I don't have a copy of the addon's source, the [The Google Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/#UnitSystems) specifies a `units` parameter with values of either `imperial` or `metric`. If you're willing to dig in to the code you should be able to find where the request is generated and fairly easily add a `units=imperial` parameter to the request.

Comment: Thanks. I've been digging around the code to try and locate  the request but didn't have any luck. I'll see what Justin comes back with.